# FaceBook Style TabBar (Slider) Corona SDK

Tags: ios, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I'm looking to build a Facebook style tab bar/sliding menu in Corona SDK, I've searched but I just cant find what I'm looking for.

I tried this in Xcode and have succeeded, I just cant get my head around it in Corona.
Yup I'm a newbie here,

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRU0inE2buQ

Answer (score 0):

found the anwser... im also looking this issue since last month.

here is the link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nsE_mwKW4pM&feature=youtu.be

thanks